# Time synchronization on cisco switches

Tags: cisco, ntp

I have LAN that must not be on Internet. I have a lot of switches. How to make core switch 4500 series to be some kind of NTP server, and all other switches to adjust their time with this core? Goal would be to set manual time only on core, and all other switches to adjust time with the core.
Does anyone know syntax for core and access switches?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

The following is an example of how to configure your devices to point to your 4500 for NTP.

There are a few things that you have to ensure you have on hand:

1. Know what time-zone the devices are operating in.
2. Know the local time (or whatever time your equipment is set to according to policy).
3. A refreshing beverage (in a non-spillable container of course.)

Configs:

> 4500# config t
>   4500(config)#ntp master
>   4500(config)#ntp authenticate
>   4500(config)#ntp authentication-keys **1** md5 **password**
>   4500(config)#int lo0
>   4500(config-int)#ip address 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.255
>   4500(config-int)#no shut
>   4500(config-int)#description Loopback_for_NTP
>   4500(config-int)#end
>   4500#clock set **hh:mm:ss** **day** **name of month** **year**
>   4500#clock timezone **number of hours you are offset from UTC**
>   4500# copy run start
>
> Client#clock set **hh:mm:ss** **day** **name of month** **year**
>   Client#clock timezone **number of hours you are offset from UTC**
>   Client#config t
>   Client(config)#ntp authenticate
>   Client(config)#ntp authentication-key **1** md5 **password**
>   Client(config)#ntp server 10.0.0.1 key 1
>   Client(config)#end
>   Client#copy run start

If I missed anything or someone sees and issue with my configuration, please let me know.

Comment: Q: why did you set the clock on the client, too? It isn't enough just to set the ntp server IP? Last one: Is clock timezone mandatory? The ntp is local, so doesn't mind about timezone.

Comment: 1)  some NTP clients complain when the drift between clocks is too high.  it often doesn't matter but there's always that one time so it doesn't hurt to build the habit.  2)  NTP never minds about the timezone. the setting of the timezone only changes how the time is displayed in the logs, etc.  It's a convenience feature since internally it's stored in universal coordinated time (or epochal depending on device ).   If you prefer viewing UTC you can leave that part out of the config.

Comment: Thanks Stuart.  You covered everything I was going to.  Technically you don't need to set the clock on the clients, but NTP has a tendency to get wonky if the client drifts too far from the master.  It doesn't happen often, but it can be annoying to troubleshoot (especially in a virtualized environment.)